# What's the difference with writing in files using DevC++ in Windows and on gcc in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, file-io, dev-c++

I find this strange difference when I write into files with DevC++ compiler on Windows and GCC compiler on Ubuntu. For a code and an input file, when I generate output file on DevC++, its size is 432Bytes. But when the same code was run for same inputs, it generates output file of 351Bytes. (Note the size of file on bottom right.)

[image]

But I notice no difference in the text. Check the [link](http://ideone.com/osSkjp) for output of `diff output.txt out_test.txt`.
Can anyone please explain why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you write/read your file in text mode and not in `ios::binary` mode.

Everytime you have a newline, one newline byte is written on ubuntu, while there are two bytes written on windows (carriage return + newline).  There might also be some differences when there are spaces at the end of a line.

Comment: Typo? `and non in` ---> `and not in`